# 2012 Great Wall V200 Turbo Diesel injector coding

Tags: diesel, fuel-injectors

I have recently installed second hand injectors. I have software to reprogram the injectors into the ECU. However, it continues to come up with an error when I enter the new injector code. I have been able to get CYLINDER 3 reprogrammed, but it will not let me do the others. Any ideas?

Cheers :)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It said, “operation failed” or something similar